# How to use set to set complex arguments of a shell functions

Tags: linux, shell, set, ash

I want to execute a function with complex arguments

I want to input them in this way (if it is possible?)

```
set [-options here] a111 "a222" "a333 a333" "a444"
set [-options here] b111 "b222" "b333 b333" "b444"
set [-options here] c111 "c222" "c333 c333" "c444"

myfunc "$@"
```

`myfunc` should see

```
a111 "a222" "a333 a333" "a444" ==> as the first argument with keeping ""
b111 "b222" "b333 b333" "b444" ==> as the second argument with keeping ""
c111 "c222" "c333 c333" "c444" ==> as the third argument with keeping ""
```

Is it possible to do that with set or with other way? and how to do it?

By the way I do not want to use `\"`

Also I can't use `'` (like `'"a333 a333"'`) since it does not evaluate vars

Comment: I regret to say that, if you refuse to use either `'` or `\"`, there is no way to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the value to have the quotes (which is an odd thing to want in general) you need to escape them from the shell.

```
$ set -- a111 '"a222"' '"a333 a333"' "\"a444\""
$ c() {
printf argc:%s\\n "$#"
printf argv:%s\\n "$@"
}
$ c "$@"
argc:4
argv:a111
argv:"a222"
argv:"a333 a333"
argv:"a444"
```

Comment: The `'` does not evaluate vars so I can't use it

Comment: and I don' want also using `\"`

Comment: Unspecified requirement in your post and that's why I gave both ways of escaping the quotes in the `set` line. Yes, I saw that update. You can't avoid escaping the quotes. The shell *will* eat them if you don't.